# android calendar library saving wrong date

Tags: android, calendar

I am using the calendar library to save the date from my app. I am using sqlite3 and can only save ints and strings to my db.   Calendar converts to a long that when converts back shows the correct date.  However to save it in my db I have to convert it to an int. When I convert the int back to a long and use setTimeInMillis(), my date changes. I know that when you covert from long to an int you lose precision. Is there a work around? I was told that I have to use the calendar library for what I am doing.  Below is the code that is giving me problems, any ideas. Already did a google search and did not have any luck

```
    long timing=0;
    timing =dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis();
    testDate.setTimeInMillis(timing);
    int dates=  (int) timing;
    timing=dates;
    testDate.setTimeInMillis(timing);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that you're losing precision. It's more that a long holds more bytes than an integer so you're gonna lose whatever data the int can't hold. You're better off converting the long to a String and storing it as that (`Long.toString(l)`). When you want to get it out of the database just parse the String into a long (`Long.parseLong(s)`).

Comment: Thanks, I have been hanging my head against the wall trying to get int to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just so that you get an idea of how limited an int is here, the maximum amount of time you can store in an int (in milliseconds) is 49 days. A long holds enough information to count milliseconds over 580 million years.

Comment: That explains a lot of problems I have been having